Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. - problem
I am looking for help from smarter colleagues. I tried many methods from the Internet, but none of them helped... Can anyone help me what could be wrong?
**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**
this is what my files look like:
local.properties:
sdk.dir=/Users/kamilpaciorek/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/kamilpaciorek/development/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1

gradle.properties:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.java.home=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.13/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false
}
dependencies {
    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.6.0')

    // TODO: Add the dependencies for Firebase products you want to use
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
}
android {
    namespace = "pl.my.app"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "27.2.12479018"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "pl.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 34
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutter.versionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutter.versionName
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.7.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:2.0.21"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.7.2" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.21" apply false
}

include ":app"

kamilpaciorek@Mac android % java -version
openjdk version "17.0.13" 2024-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.13+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17.0.13+0, mixed mode, sharing)
kamilpaciorek@Mac android % kotlin -version
Kotlin version 2.0.21-release-482 (JRE 17.0.13+0)
kamilpaciorek@Mac android % ./gradlew -version

Gradle 8.10.2
Build time:    2024-09-23 21:28:39 UTC
Revision:      415adb9e06a516c44b391edff552fd42139443f7
Kotlin:        1.9.24
Groovy:        3.0.22
Ant:           Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.14 compiled on August 16 2023
Launcher JVM:  17.0.13 (Homebrew 17.0.13+0)
Daemon JVM:    '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.13/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home' (from org.gradle.java.home)
OS:            Mac OS X 15.0.1 aarch64
Someone help me solve my problem?
I work on the latest Android Studio, the latest Flutter, and Mac mini m2 Pro
changing the throat to 8.11.1 does nothing. distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.11.1-all.zip

try to move your stuff to a new project also set your jdk like this flutter config --jdk-dir /your/path/jvm/java-17-openjdk/ also try to use higher gradle and agp versions
